# Understanding deploy url and base href

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm developing an Angular app which I need to deploy on path

> https://examplePath/AppSection/myApp

There is a server which redirect http://examplePath/AppSection to http://localhost:8080.

So, what I thinked to do is to set, in my Angular.json, the base href property like this:

```
"serve": {
[..]
"options": {
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"port": 8080,
"browserTarget": "myApp:build",
"baseHref": "/myApp/"
},
[...]
```

Doing this the app was accessible but all the calls to runtime.js, polyfill.js, main.js, etc... doesn't work because the browser tryed to find these file on

> http://examplePath/myApp

Then I read about the deployUrl property so I set the angular.json like that:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
           "options": {"deployUrl": "https://examplePath/AppSection/",
[...]

"serve": {
    [..]
    "options": {
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": 8080,
        "browserTarget": "myApp:build",
        "baseHref": "/myApp/"
    },
[...]
```

This configuration works but with several issues and the browser usually remove AppSection/ from the url (I don't know why).
Then I edited my baseHref property adding AppSection/ and the result is:

> "deployUrl": "https://examplePath/AppSection/"
>
> "baseHref": "/AppSection/myApp/"

This configuration works but the browser has some problems with sockjs-node:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://examplePath/sockjs-node/570/wwadpefk/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 GET
>
> https://examplePath/sockjs-node/570/00lb5fwe/eventsource 404 (Not Found) VM3475 sockjs.bundle.js:1
>
> GET https://examplePath/sockjs-node/570/kqry21k3/htmlfile?c=_jp.a5d54nx 404 (Not Found)
>
> Refused to display 'https://examplePath/sockjs-node/570/kqry21k3/htmlfile?c=_jp.a5d54nx' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Honestly I do not understood what I should do to deploy on a specific path.